# System tray tooltip formatting

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, tooltip, system-tray

I am creating a `NotifyIcon` and then calling this to show a balloon-tip from the system tray:

```
_trayIcon.ShowBalloonTip(100000, notifierTitle, notifierText, ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

Everything works fine but I wondered: is there any way to format the text in a system tray tooltip? (In my case, `notifierText`)

Obviously, I am adding newline characters etc. but I would like certain parts to be **bold** or *italic* and maybe even add [blue hyperlinked text](http://stackoverflow.com) to separate lines in the tooltip.

I am aware of the events that are available and they don't cover this sort of thing.

I'm sure I've seen it done elsewhere...

So is it possible, and if so, how do I do it??

Comment: [Why can't I put hotlinks in notification icon balloon tooltips?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/25/79842.aspx)  – from Raymond Chen's wonderful blog every Windows programmer should (must?) read.

Comment: @Joey: Thanks. That explains not parsing links. Bold/italic text still seems reasonable though.

Comment: I'm not it is possible on the default NotifyIcon class or without getting down and dirty with Win32 and P/Invoke. However, I recently wanted extra functionality that the standard BalloonTip did not provide so I created a custom windows form and gave that the appearance I wanted - such as fade-in/fade-out etc.

Comment: Thanks peter, I was hoping to avoid that. Its not a high priority though, its just a personal project so I can leave it till later or work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a ever so slight hint that this might be possible if you run on Vista or higher.  From the documentation of NOTIFYICONDATA:

> When uVersion is set to
>   NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4, the standard
>   ToolTip is replaced by the
>   application-drawn pop-up user
>   interface (UI)

But with any hints whatsoever how to actually make this work.  Googling for +NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4 +ToolTip doesn't produce anything relevant.  It also isn't wrapped by the Windows API Code Pack.  I'm guessing that it takes listening for callback notifications.

At any rate, you will have to completely replace the NotifyIcon class to make this work.  Maybe your google fu can get you a better hit.